# Head function throwing type match errors Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So basically i'm taking a list of items and adding to a list of tuples to make it more efficient way to store/view the data. My code is

```
TList :: [a] -> a -> [(a,Int)] -> [(a,Int)]
TList head [a] [] = [(head [a],1)]
TList head [a] ((a',i):xa)
    |a' == take 1 = (head 1,i+1):xa
    |otherwise = (a',i) : TList drop 1 [a] xa
```

so my logic is that I take the first item in the list, checks to see if its already in the tuple list, if it is add one to the int. the call the function again but without the first list item
but it keeps giving the error

```
Couldn't match expected type '[t1] -> a' with actual type '[a]'
```

it gives this error 5 times, one for each line.

Comment: Your function as written won't even parse: function identifiers must begin with a lower-case letter. Please make sure that you are showing us your code *exactly* as it is written.

Answer (score 4):

So, this is not a full answer to your question because I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve. But there's a few things wrong with the code and I suggest you start by fixing them and then seeing how it goes:

1. Function names need to begin with a lower-case letter. Therefore, `TList` is not a legal name for a function. (Types and type constructors have upper case names). So maybe you want `tList`?
2. You are naming one of the parameters `head`. But `head` is also a `Prelude` function and you actually seem to use the `head` function (`head [a]`). But your parameter `head` will shadow the head function. Also `head` seems like an odd name for a proper list.
3. `head [a]` seems odd as `head [a] == a`. So the head of a list with just one element is always just that element.
4. I'm guessing you're trying to use `drop 1 [a]` (if so, you're missing parenthesis). That's odd too because `drop 1 [a] == []`. `drop 1` of a list with just one element is always the empty list.
5. You're pattern matching the second parameter (type `a`) with `[a]` and that can't work because `[a]` only works with list types `[t]`.
6. `a' == take 1` doesn't really make sense. `take 1` needs a list as the second argument `take 1 [1, 2, 3] = [1]`. So you're comparing something (`a`) of type `a` with another thing of type `[a] -> [a]` (`take 1 :: [a] -> [a]`).

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote:

```
TList head [a] [] = ...
```

You've shadowed the original `head` function. Thus in this context:

```
[(head [a],1)]
```

It tries to evaluate it. I've no idea why haven'y you just used `a` here, the code is very unclear and it won't compile with that name (uppercase `TList`), but this is the source of this type mismatch.